# How to run monkey testing ONLY in application?

Tags: monkey

How  to run monkey testing ONLY in testing application?
How can I set border for monkey testing. I don't want that it touches any button out of my testing application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html). You can use the option `-p` to limit your test in specific package.

Something like this:

```
adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v 500
```

Comment: How to make speed of click not very fast?

Comment: @PonomarenkoOleh try to use `--throttle` parameter followed by time between two event.